# Creating a new namespace in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

When I googled "create new namespace in mediawiki", I got [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Using_custom_namespaces#Creating_a_custom_namespace). I have created a new namespace using this technique and it worked perfectly. After that because of curiosity I **searched** in the **mediawiki search bar** for **"Testnamespace:testpage"** where "Testnamespace" namespace is not there in my wiki and got a link for creating a new page. So my question is :

**Does this create a new namespace("Testnamespace") in the wiki without modifying LocalSettings.php with those codes in the above link?**

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create a namespace without editing your wiki's configuration. If you create a page titled "A:B" where "A" is not a valid namespace, "A:B" will just be a page in main namespace (namespace 0).